# In variable selection, Lasso over-penalizes coefficients. How to prevent?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, regularization

I was doing some simulation on the Lasso. Particularly, I set p=200 variables, where only the first 5 have non-zero coefficients. I generated a training sample of size n=100. Whatever I do to tune the hyper parameter lambda, it is hard to find a good lambda that do well in both variable selection (only the first 5 variables have nonzero coefficients) and prediction (low prediction error). The reason I observe is that we need to reach a certain value of lambda to leave only 5 nonzero coefficients, however, the estimated 5 coefficients become very small and almost have no effect due to the penalization by the large lambda.

Is there a way that we can manipulate the data to make Lasso work well in both variable selection and prediction?

P.S. I know doing an extra adaptive Lasso step may help a little bit, but is there any way that we can solve this by manipulating the data (transformations) only?

Comment: Could you do elastic net and add in some ridge regression?

Comment: Hi @Dave, that's one option, but I was exploring the properties of the Lasso only. In theory, it works well, however the issue is there in practice.

Comment: I would argue that *precisely* in practice, variable selection is a non-issue. You will never have a situation where you have five predictors with nonzero coefficients and 195 predictors with coefficients that are *exactly* zero. (Why would you have them in your pool of predictors in the first place if most of them were irrelevant?) So-called "tapering effect sizes" are far more likely. And then it comes down to the bias-variance tradeoff, which the lasso is very good at.

Comment: "is there any way that we can solve this" - yes, get more data

Comment: We use $\ell_1$ as a proxy for the actual norm we really wanted, the non-convex $\ell_0$. There's a trade-off attached

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be asking too much of Lasso. Even in the first simulation, Example 1 in the original paper (available from [here](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html)), Lasso only chose the "correct" model about 1/4 of the time. And that was with 3 out of 8 predictors having non-zero coefficients, a high signal-to-noise ratio, and more observations (20 per simulation) than predictors.

In Example 3 of that paper, with only 1 non-zero coefficient among 8 predictors and an even higher signal-to-noise ratio than in Example 1 above, Lasso only found 2 or 3 predictors excluded (depending on how the penalization value was chosen), instead of the 7 with true 0 values.

With what you are simulating--only 5 non-zero coefficients out of 200 predictors, and fewer observations than predictors--it would seem to be much harder to get simultaneous strict variable selection (down to the "true" 5 out of 200) and good prediction.